# Android TextView afterTextChanged call with unexpected Editable

Tags: android

InputMethodManager

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

At Chinese InputMethod. when I input "西安市", I expected the log as follow.

```
afterTextChanged 西
afterTextChanged 西安
afterTextChanged 西安市
```

But the actual log as follow.

```
 afterTextChanged x
 afterTextChanged xi
 afterTextChanged 西
 afterTextChanged a
 afterTextChanged an
 afterTextChanged 安
 ....
```

If I use 'Speed Dial' style to input the Chinese word.
The log got worse！！！

```
E: afterTextChanged() t
E: afterTextChanged() t'x
E: afterTextChanged() t'z'z
E: afterTextChanged() t'y'y's
E: afterTextChanged() 挺有意思
```

The code is follow.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   Log.i(TAG, "afterTextChanged "+s.toString());
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you use a simulator Android device rather than a truly Android mobile phone？ I use my mobile phone to run the same code. But the log is coming out not as you expected or described.

My phone is Nexus 6p, Android 7.1.1, Default input method.

[image]

it did not put the word '西安市' into EditText until 西安市 was chosen completed. So, in my case, `afterTextChanged` only occurred once when 西安市 was chosen completed.

Comment: What’s your 'input method'?

Comment: I upload a gif image. My 'Input method' is 'HUAWEI Swype'

Comment: Sogou, Baidu,  XunFei don't happens. As your description. The Device is 'HUAWEI MT7 TL00' , Android 6.0

Comment: My input method is Gboard, named '谷歌拼音输入法' in Chinese.